# Creating responsive CSS scoreboard with numeric values immediately to the left of bars

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to write a simple, responsive scoreboard with HTML and CSS. For each player (three total), there will be a bar (a div with a height, width, and background-color), and a numeric score immediately to the right of the bar.

I wish for the bars to be in a column flex container. The topmost bar will always take up the full width of the flex container. The width of the second two bars could then be set relative to that of the first bar. If the second player scored half as much as the first, the width of their bar would be set to 50%.

Is it possible to use this approach while also positioning the numeric scores immediately to the right of the bars? I previously tried keeping each bar in a div with its corresponding numeric score, but it became very difficult to set the width of the bars accurately.

Here's the code I have right now:

```css
span {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #7B7B7B;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

#names {
    padding-right: 2%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#player1name, #player2name, #player3name {
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

#bars {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#player1bar, #player2bar, #player3bar {
    height: 2em;
    flex: 1;
}

#player1bar {
    background-color: #4776d2;
    width: 100%;
}

#player2bar {
    background-color: #2a85b6;
    width: 50%;
}

#player3bar {
    background-color: #51636d;
    width: 7.5%;
}

#scores {
    padding-left: 2%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#player1score, #player2score, #player3score {
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="names">
        <span id="player1name">Alice</span>
        <span id="player2name">Bob</span>
        <span id="player3name">Charlie</span>
    </div>

    <div id="bars">
        <div id="player1bar"></div>
        <div id="player2bar"></div>
        <div id="player3bar"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="scores">
        <span id="player1score">10,000</span>
        <span id="player2score">5,000</span>
        <span id="player3score">750</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something kind of this?

```css
span {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #7B7B7B;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

#names {
    padding-right: 2%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#player1name, #player2name, #player3name {
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

#bars {
    flex: 1;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#player1bar, #player2bar, #player3bar {
    height: 2em;
    flex: 1;
}

#player1bar {
    background-color: #4776d2;
    width: 100%;
}

#player2bar {
    background-color: #2a85b6;
    width: 50%;
}

#player3bar {
    background-color: #51636d;
    width: 7.5%;
}

#scores {
    padding-left: 2%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#player1score, #player2score, #player3score {
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

.bars {
    width: 90%;
}

.bar {
    position: relative;
}

.bar span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-40%);
    left: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="names">
        <span id="player1name">Alice</span>
        <span id="player2name">Bob</span>
        <span id="player3name">Charlie</span>
    </div>

    <div class="bars">
        <div class="bar" id="player1bar">
            <div></div>
            <span id="player1score">10,000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar" id="player2bar">
            <div></div>
            <span id="player2score">5,000</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar" id="player3bar">
            <div></div>
            <span id="player3score">750</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I changed the html structure a bit because the your one wasn't easy to remake.

One tip, use more classes rather than id's. It is easier to write css for classes.